# How to put data from the selector to the desired block?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 left_header">Goals</div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 group_bar right_line_goals group0" id="group0"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 left_header">Value</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 group_bar right_line_value group0" id="group1"></div>
</div>
...
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 left_header">Value</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 group_bar right_line_value group0" id="group1"></div>
</div>
...
```

I need to put my data to each "div" where class "group0..." and id "group0". Numbers from class and id will concatenate, for example: group0, group1.

Q: How can I get a selector in the method to choose the block with the class and id to select a tag?

**Data for example. group and tag not object, just string:**

```
data = 30;

group = .group0;

tag = #group1;
```

**The method in which I pass the data and must be necessary `like group.add(tag)..` selector for embedding information.**

```
    Graphics.prototype.diagram = function(data, group, tag) {
        var group = $(group),
            tag = $(tag);

        group.add(tag).jqChart({
            legend: { visible: false },
```

Comment: Ok! Can you write me for example, how I can get selector in my method for correct put data in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern that often helps to initialize plugins that require instance specific data is to initialize them within an `each` loop.

```
$('.group0').each(function(index, elem){
   var $this =$(this);
   /* do something with element or traverse from element to get data for plugin*/

   /* now initialize plugin with element specific variable data */

   $this.jqChart({ /* opts */});

});
```

Comment: Probably I did not understand correctly. I need to constantly call this function for each group to fill the data. Groups may be a large number, like: .group0, .group1, ... But the ID is needed in order to determine which figure to be inserted into the unit.But the ID is needed in order to determine where to insert the data.

Comment: use `data-` attributes rather than ID. But either way above approach is what you need. Within loop `var id=this.id`

Comment: These are executed in a loop:
Graphics.prototype.diagram(data[title], '.group0', '#group0');
Graphics.prototype.diagram(data[title], '.group0', '#group1');
Graphics.prototype.diagram(data[title], '.group0', '#group2');

after that

Graphics.prototype.diagram(data[title], '.group1', '#group0');
Graphics.prototype.diagram(data[title], '.group1', '#group1');

Comment: right, so call `Graphics.diagram()` inside the `each loop` or just initialize the chart plugin directly